# background image [gradient] accommodate new screen ratio/resolution [android]

Tags: java, android, gradient, resolution, screen-resolution

So we're starting to see phones and tablets ditch the 16:9 1920x1080 standard

> Essential phone 16:10 2560 x 1312
>
> Galaxy s8 18.5:9 2960x1440
>
> LG G6 18:9 1440 x 2880

Even apple seems to be headed in this direction with iphone X

So now the problem...

I'm trying to create a 4 corner gradient (1 color in each corner and they all
blend into each other) that encompasses the screen.

The problem is android only supports 2-color blending and I want this gradient to be high fidelity across multiple screen sizes.

I've tried

- Alpha Blending... create 4 gradients in each corner and make them fade to 0 alpha. However alpha belnding isn't a true color blend, thus the colors will look dull or one is overpowering

some other options

- Create a run-time gradient blend and save the bitmap to conserve speed for future app openings. This seems ideal although more thought intensive, i don't know the algorithm or how to create the bitmap
- Create multiple images of the gradient at different aspect ratios/screen sizes

Maybe this is a non-issue and I shouldn't care if a background image gets stretched, but what's the consensus on background images to fit these weird ratios? or does anyone know how to create a 4-way gradient that doesn't care about ratio

Comment: tried `android.graphics.ComposeShader`?

Comment: @pskink I haven't heard of it. I'll look into it.